# ImageDataGenerator doesn't display the image colors of my RGB processing_function (Using openCV)

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, computer-vision

I am trying to pass a `processing_function` to my `ImageDataGenerator` that does a color-based segmentation, it basically keeps just the green pixels of the image. I explain in the code each line:

```
def segmented(image):

#Input is a NumPy array rank 3
np_image = np.array(image)

#Keras uses load_img to read the images in RGB

# For segmentation, we convert to HSV to get the mask
hsv_foto = cv2.cvtColor(foto, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

#The mask threshold: green colors
colormin=(25,50,50)
colormax=(86,255,255)

# Get the mask
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_foto, colormin , colormax)

#Apply the mask on the RGB image (foto= RGB so result= RGB as well)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(foto, foto, mask=mask)

#Keras reads the images with pillow so we convert to Pil image
 pil_image= Image.fromarray(result)

#Return a NumPy array rank 3
return pil_image
```

This function works fine while  [visualizing the segmented images](https://ibb.co/hfnznYT) with a small change in the first line (I use cv2.imread to open the images).

**The problem** is while passing this function to my `ImageDataGenerator` as a `processing_function`.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2,
    preprocessing_function = segmented)
```

Basically, I get this error while visualizing the `ImageDataGenerator`'s transformation results with `x,y = train_generator.next()`

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'Image' and 'float'`

Does anyone know why is this error?

Comment: ِDid you check the output type? Is it float? multiply the image to 255 and see if it's correct.

Comment: I checked and it seems correct!  Here is the output (https://ibb.co/9y8Ff7Y) dtype=uint8

Comment: Put some logs between the commands in segmented, and see where the data become to zero.

Comment: @Meisam What do you mean exactly? The function works fine before ImageDataGenerator but returns black images after it. At which point should I put the logs between commands? Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Just put print(foto), print(hsv_foto), ... in the segmented function and run your code. Yo will catch the first command that makes zero array.

Comment: @MH304 Thank you for help! I checked the code and there is no problem with it. I converted the output to pil_image because I read that Keras reads images with pillow but I get the error I have in my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence

```
foto = cv2.cvtColor(np_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
hsv_foto = cv2.cvtColor(foto, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

is not doing what you may expect, since `foto` is RGB, not BGR.

Try

```
hsv_foto = cv2.cvtColor(np_image, cv2.COLOR_BRG2HSV)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I am sorry I think I had a typo in my code, I corrected it: I tried both combinations but it didn't work. Could you plz check my corrected code again!